# Is the Community Bot trying to take over the world?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed a couple of times recently in which the Community Bot acted swiftly and decisively when I would have expected a more protracted process.

First, I noticed an answer that had been "flagged as abusive or spam," and deleted and locked by the Community Bot. Looking at [the revision history](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/132638/revisions), it looks pretty innocuous. Maybe plagiarized or suspected AI content, but not abuse and not shilling anything. I was surprised that one flag got it frozen so quickly.

Then just now, on [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/132653/78419), I proposed a duplicate, and within minutes it was closed *as* a duplicate, saying only "closed by" myself and Community Bot. I'm surprised it didn't require more votes to close.

So what's up, is Skynet taking over?

Comment: First of all, yes. But ... I was also mystified at the first answer you mention. It hadn't been removed, but it had more downvotes than upvotes, which seemed odd. So AI bot seems like a good guess. For the closed question, my understanding is that mods can log in as the community bot, so it may be that that your close vote might have popped up while one of our mods was so logged in.

Answer (score 5):

The [first post](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/132638/53709) you mention, was not written by a human, it's the output of some generative-AI (such as ChatCPT).   But what's more, there is a spam link in the very last paragraph (where it is easy to miss).  This link was noticed by the SmokeDetector (a community bot) and brought to the attention of the [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) team.

Several experienced Charcoal users from across the SE network reviewed the post and agreed that is was indeed spam.  They promptly flagged the post as such, which resulted in deletion and locking.

---

As for the [second post](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/132653/why-cant-i-relate-notes-to-sound), you suggest that it was possibly a duplicate.  Normally it would take several users to agree, or at least one user with a gold badge for that tag.

However, if the asker themselves agrees, then this is also enough to have the question closed as a duplicate.  When the user isn't able to vote-to-close, this action is attributed to the Community Bot.

Comment: Oh btw, do we have some kind of AI-detection tools at our disposal by now (is that part of what Charcoal is about)? Or are we just making educated guesses, like "gee, smells like AI"?

Comment: @Andy_Bonner  
Charcoal is not about AI, it's about spam (usually detected by analysing links), but it also finds Rude/Abusive posts.

Comment: To me, this answer instantly looks AI generated because of its form and formatting.  Reading the details critically reveals its "thoughts" are not well organised.  It uses all the right words, but doesn't even really try to say anything.  

The link disguised near the end is a giveaway.  On other SE sites there is lots of AI-spam just like this.

I don't think there are any AI-detection tools endorsed by SE, but there are plenty you can find online (unfortunately they aren't particularly accurate or reliable).

Answer (score 3):

Think of the Community Bot as what happens when automation happened. In the first case it was flagged and accepted as spam (and the user later destroyed due to it). The link included at the bottom is spam and when a new user introduces spam like that, accepting spam flags will happen and the Community Bot will delete it once the flag is accepted. The spam flags are also where the extra downvotes came from.

The second the user who posted the question agreed with the duplicate which closes it automatically, but since the user doesn't have the privilege it shows as the Community Bot.